# recursive selection sort proof of correctness

Tags: haskell, induction, proof-of-correctness

I need to prove that the following [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) code (in Haskell) is always sorting:

```
import Data.List (minimum, delete)

ssort :: Ord t => [t] -> [t]
ssort [] = []
ssort xs = let { x = minimum xs } in  x : ssort (delete x xs)
```

We can assume that we have a function called "**sorted**" that checks when a list is sorted.

Statement to prove by structural induction: **sorted(ssort xs)**

I tried the following but I was not able to complete the proof. Can you please help me out to complete the proof?

---

**Base case: xs = []**

> sorted(ssort xs) =
>
> sorted(ssort []]) =
>
> sorted([]])
>
> correct since sorted([]) is always sorted

---

**Inductive step**

IH (inductive hypothesis) = sorted(ssort xs)

show: sorted(ssort y#xs)

> **case I: x = y = minimum**
>
> sorted(ssort y#xs) =
>
> sorted(let { x = minimum (y#xs)} in  x : ssort (delete x (y#xs))) =
>   (by definition)
>
> sorted(let { y = minimum (y#xs)} in  y : ssort (delete y (y#xs))) =
>   (by substitution)
>
> sorted(y : ssort (delete y (y#xs))) =
>
> sorted(y : ssort (xs)) = (by delete definition)
>
> sorted(y : ssort (xs))
>
> by IH we know that ssort (xs) is sorted, also y is the minimum value
>   so it goes first
>
> **case II: y is not minimum**
>
> sorted(ssort y#xs) =
>
> sorted(let { x = minimum (y#xs)} in  x : ssort (delete x (y#xs))) =
>   (by definition)
>
> .....
>
> no idea

Comment: Side note: to prove the sorting function correct, you need to demonstrate two more things: 1. That the computation eventually terminates, and 2. That the the result of the function is a permutation of its argument (no element has been dropped, doubled, or added).

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I suspect you will find it easier to prove an implementation of insertion sort correct, which will lead you more or less directly to proving a mergesort correct. Proving selection sort correct seems like a bit of a dead end; some similar ideas show up in heap sort, but in considerably different clothing.

Comment: @dfeuer I'll admit that the cases given elide some detail, but aren't both termination and permutation essentially covered by the same induction as presented? Read the induction on `n` to be "`ssort` terminates with correct output (ie. a sorted permutation) of any input of length `n`". Yes, we assume some typeclass laws connecting the `eq`, `ord` instances, some properties of `delete`, and probably a couple other things but the essential structure of the proof doesn't need modification to account for those details?

Comment: @moonGoose, you may be right. I know it can be rather tricky to get the permutation bit right in formal proofs, but it's probably not bad in informal ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inductive hypothesis is too weak. You should assume that `ssort` works correctly on *any* list of length `k` rather than *some specific* list `xs` of length `k`.

So, instead, assuming `ssort` is correct on any list of length `k` and letting `xs` be any list of length `k+1`,

```
ssort xs 
= let x = minimum xs in x : ssort (delete x xs) -- by definition of `ssort`
= let x = minimum xs in x : sorted (delete x xs) -- `delete x xs` has length `k` so `ssort` sorts it correctly by IH
= sorted xs -- by definition of sorted, minimum, delete
```